# How to access the rootViewController when using BlackBerry Dynamics SDK

Tags: swift, blackberry, ios13, rootviewcontroller

I'm delevolping an iOS 13 app with several view controllers (using storyboard, without navigation controller, without launchscreen).
For dismissing / presenting the view controllers I use the following code:

```
@objc func onMenuItemUploadsTap(_ sender: UIView) {
    self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let vc = appDelegate.getViewController(viewController: .Uploads)
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController!.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Once a viewController is instantiated I keep them in AppDelegate because a user can jump from viewController to viewController
and therefore a viewController has to keep it's state / values, that's why am using:

```
let vc = appDelegate.getViewController(viewController: .Uploads)
```

Ok... when I run the app in release mode, only the initial viewController (named: HomeController) is shown, not the 'vc' which I like to present and the debug console let me know:

```
Attempt to present <XXX.UploadController: 0x7ffc71152400> on <UIViewController: 0x7ffc70714c40> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Note: UIViewController: 0x7ffc70714c40 is NOT the HomeController!
('HomeController' is marked in storyboard as: Is Initial View Controller)

In debug mode (without BlackBerry SDK) the app runs fine.

My AppDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
#if !DEBUG
    XXXGDiOSDelegate.sharedInstance.appDelegate = self
    GDiOS.sharedInstance().authorize(XXXGDiOSDelegate.sharedInstance)
#else
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController") as? HomeController
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = controller
#endif
    return true
}
```

My Question:
How can I access the rootViewController when using the BlackBerry SDK ?

I'm using: 
macOS Mojave 10.14.6, xCode 11.1 (11A1027), BlackBerry_Dynamics_SDK_for_iOS_v6.1.0.170

Thanks in advance!

I tried:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController") as? HomeController
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = controller

#if !DEBUG
    XXXGDiOSDelegate.sharedInstance.appDelegate = self
    GDiOS.sharedInstance().authorize(XXXGDiOSDelegate.sharedInstance)
#endif
    return true
}
```

and

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
#if !DEBUG
    XXXGDiOSDelegate.sharedInstance.appDelegate = self
    GDiOS.sharedInstance().authorize(XXXGDiOSDelegate.sharedInstance)
#endif

    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController") as? HomeController
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = controller

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution... I followed this instructions (objective-c):

https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/blackberry-dynamics/ios/_app_user_interface_restrictions.html

(see there: Instantiating The Application User Interface)

...and implemented this in my AppDelegate:

Member variable:

```
var run_once: Bool = false
```

modified didAuthorize:

```
func didAuthorize() -> Void {

    print(#file, #function)

    //I added this if block:
    if !self.run_once {
        self.run_once = true
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController") as? HomeController
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = controller
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController = controller
    }
}
```

Now the app runs fine in release mode too.